# TestDriven.NET and native C Library

Tags: c#, c, xunit.net, testdriven.net, native-methods

I am working on a C# application that makes calls to a native Windows C dll.  We use TestDriven.NET with xUnit for testing. The problem is, whenever we run unit tests that use the C library (which we did not write),  and then try to build afterwards, there is a build error about how the library is being used by another process.  To fix it, you have to kill the TestDriven system tray app which was left behind.  We are calling a method the library provides to free its memory, but it doesn't seem to help.  Does anyone know of a way to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem since we are building a native clr profiler. Strangely enough
windows lets you rename the dll but not delete it.
A work around can be to create a pre-build step that renames the existing dll before the build.
Also I suggest to contact [Jamie Cansdale](http://weblogs.asp.net/nunitaddin/default.aspx) the author of TD.NET and report this problem. He's got a great support.